# Opening MPK file without ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: mapinfo, map-package

Is there any way to open an ArcGIS map package (`*.mpk`) file with MapInfo?

I do not have access to ArcGIS Desktop.

Answer (score 13):

Inside an MPK you'll find an MXD and a fGDB. (You may find shapefiles, tiffs or other files depending on how the MPK was created, but odds are you'll find data in the fGDB).

With this knowledge, if you have an application other than ArcGIS that can read MXDs and fGDB, you can simply unzip an MPK (using something like [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html). The built in Windows Zip Extractor software will not work) to get at the contents.

As for a program that offers native support to read an MPK that isn't Arc* -- I haven't heard of any.

Comment: ...and QGIS will read the fGDB you find inside--no need to purchase any other software.

Comment: couldn't get qgis to understand the file, but did rename .mpk extension to .zip and os x could understand/uncompress it. really appreciate this answer! thank you so much!

Comment: Built-in Windows Explorer uncompress doesn't always work for me, but 7Zip does.

Answer (score 2):

Change the file extension from .mpk to .zip. Attempting to open the file should automatically unzip the contents.

Comment: It works if after changing the extension to .zip, one unzips the content of the file with a specific unzipping program, saves the content and then opens them in QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

This method works for Mac OS if the default Archive Utility did not work.

1. Change the file extension from `.mpk` to `.zip`
2. Download [keka](https://www.keka.io/en/) and install on Mac
3. Right click file and open with keka