# Opening ArcScene *.spk file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, convert, arcscene

I have an ArcScene *.spk file, but no longer have ArcScene and only a Basic License for ArcGIS.

I have access to QGIS.

Is there any way to open / import the *.spk file to extract some of the features out of the file?

Comment: Was your `*.spk` (scene layer package) created using ArcGIS Pro or ArcScene?  I've never created one and my quick look at the help finds ArcGIS Pro but not ArcScene documentation.  Can you provide the precise steps that you used to create it?

Comment: Alas I didn't generate it. It's from an old project and I thought the data would be useful. We have a alternative that isn't as great, but will still get the job done, but generally I couldn't find anything and wondered if there was something obvious that I was missing.

Comment: You can get a free 21-day trial of ArcGIS. That should be long enough to open the .spk and extract the data to a more accessible file format. http://www.esri.com/arcgis/trial/

Answer (score 1):

An `*.spk` file is a scene layer package that may have been created by ArcGIS Pro (or possibly ArcScene but I cannot find that documented).  After ArcGIS Pro 1.3 these are named `*.slpk` files.

Although you can probably examine its raw contents by using 7zip (see [Opening MPK file without ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137689/opening-mpk-file-without-arcgis-desktop)), I think the best way to try and examine its rendered contents may be if you can find someone with ArcGIS Pro and or ArcGIS Desktop (with 3D Analyst licensing).

I am doubtful that QGIS will be able to make much of an `*.spk` file but I am sometimes surprised.