# Map package of ArcGIS to use in QGIS

Tags: qgis, map-package

I have a Map Package of ArcGIS and my licence expired. I need to use this file now.  I am using QGIS.

How do I do this?

Comment: What file format/extension is the Map Package in?

Comment: @TeddyTedTed, I would assume it is mpk - http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-arcmap/creating-a-map-package.htm

Answer (score 8):

DISCLAIMER: I have not actually done this, this is just based on Googling your question. But I may be able to help until someone who knows better comes along. Also I am assuming that the Map Package is a .mpk file (Thanks @Houska).

First of all make a backup of the Map Package.

Change the extension of the file from .mpk to .zip and unzip it.

It should contain a file geodatabase or/and shapefiles and other data.

Once you unpack those you should be able to load them in QGIS. [See this question for loading a geodatabase in QGIS.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/installing-file-geodatabase-gdb-support-in-qgis)

As for symbology there is no way (yet) to import ArcGIS (.lyr) symbology into QGIS, but [NorthRoadGeo is working on it.](https://twitter.com/northroadgeo/status/1092216748634337280)

Comment: I see our answers, typed at the same time, and based on a mix of google and personal experience are similar!

Comment: @Houska Haha yeah, pretty much the same.

Comment: I've tried this approach and worked fine, thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming it's a MPK file, which is a container that should hold a number of files that together fully describe the ArcGIS mapping project in a transferable way.

You should be able to open the .mpk with a ZIP file utility and extract the components.

The map layers should be inside as (f)GDB files which can probably just be opened with QGIS, or if that fails converted with ogr2ogr with the `OpenFileGDB` (as opposed to `FileGDB`) driver.

Information about symbology, styling, map composition etc -- what in the QGIS world would be the project, not sure of ArcGIS terminology -- is in a proprietary MXD file. There's a recent announcement of a project to translate that too (see http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/arcgis/ ) but you will probably have to recreate that, and if you are intending to work with the data in QGIS going forward, it's a good idea anyway.

(This answer based in part on my brief experience successfully opening .gdb without ArcGIS, unsuccessful attempts to use a .mxd I inherited, and in part on [Opening MPK file without ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137689/opening-mpk-file-without-arcgis-desktop) which references MapInfo not QGIS but is relevant.)