# Saving data in table of contents list (raster, shp, etc.) all at once in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, save, map-package

After loading the file in ArcMap, when you save ArcMap, it is saved as an .mxd file. This mxd file stores the file path.

Is there a way to save all data in my Table of contents list to a folder I specify?

When working, I bring it from various folders, check it, and analyze it. And when I give the analyzed data to someone else, there is a hassle of having to re-save it for each individual file.

Answer (score 2):

It seem you are looking for the "Map Package" functionality :

> **[Creating a map package](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-arcmap/creating-a-map-package.htm)**
>
> Map packages (.mpk) make it easy to share complete map documents with
> others. A map package contains a map document (.mxd) and the data
> referenced by the layers it contains, packaged into one convenient,
> portable file. Map packages can be used for easy sharing of maps
> between colleagues in a work group, across departments in an
> organization, or with any other ArcGIS users via ArcGIS Online. Map
> packages have other uses, too, such as the ability to create an
> archive of a particular map that contains a snapshot of the current
> state of the data used in the map.

Note that this is intended by ESRI for sharing with ArcGIS user and use ESRI specific format so if you need to share with non ESRI user this is not a perfect solution (you may uncompress the map package and retrieve the data but that add more steep to the procedure. See these link for using a map package with [QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312904/map-package-of-arcgis-to-use-in-qgis) and [MapInfo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137689/opening-mpk-file-without-arcgis-desktop))